# a bit of javascript metaprogramming & chainable setters

Tags: javascript, metaprogramming, fluent

I've got a need for 'chainable' setters, allowing you to do things like:

```
cool_shoes = new Shoes().color('glitter').style('platform')
console.log(cool_shoes.color()) // => 'glitter'
```

But I've gotten tired of writing the same getter and setter code over and over, to wit:

```
function Shoes() { this._color = null; this._style = null; }
Shoes.prototype.constructor = Shoes;

Shoes.prototype.color = function(arg) {
    if (arguments.length === 0) {
        return this._color;  // _slot accessor
    } else {
        this._color = arg;   // _slot setter
        return this;
    };
};

Shoes.prototype.style = function(arg) {
    if (arguments.length === 0) {
        return this._style;  // _slot accessor
    } else {
        this._style = arg;   // _slot setter
        return this;
    };
};
```

I mean, that works, but it's a lot of repetition when you *should* be able to do something like along the lines of:

```
function createGetterSetter(getter, setter) {
    return function(arg) {
        if (arguments.length === 0) {
            return getter();
        } else {
            setter(arg);
            return this;
        };
    };
};
```

and then use it like this:

```
Shoes.prototype.color = createGetterSetter(
    function() { return this._color; },
    function(arg) { this._color = arg; });

Shoes.prototype.style = createGetterSetter(
    function() { return this._style; },
    function(arg) { this._style = arg; });
```

Of course as any hard-working javascript wizard knows, it won't work: `this` won't be bound to the correct value when the `getter` or `setter` is called.

Despite my best efforts to sprinkle `.bind(this)` in all the right places, I still haven't gotten it to work.  This should be relatively simple, but what am I missing?

#### update

There are some imaginative and elegant answers here, I'm still going with [Bryan Chen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37288793/558639) for a previously tacit reason: my setters and getters need to do more than simply reference object attributes.  For example, in my real application, I have calls to `createGetterSetter` that look like this:

```
Command.prototype.messageType = utils.createGetterSetter(
    function() { return messageType(this._payload).toString(); },
    function(str) { messageType(this._payload).write(str); });
```

... so solutions that simply get or set a slot in the object won't work in my case.  But thank you all for some great answers!

Comment: You should be doing `getter.call(this)`/`setter.call(this, arg)` instead of using `bind` anywhere.

Comment: Actually I would have expected `createGetterSetters(Shoes.prototype, ["color", "style"])` if your aim was to avoid repetion :-)

Comment: @Bergi for this example that signature would work, but in general, getters and setters may want more functionality than just assigning or returning a particular field

Comment: @PatrickRoberts: Actually I find those rather rare :-) And you could still create an actual setter/getter for the `_…` property if you really needed it.

Comment: @Bergi, consider functions in JQuery which handles several different signatures of the same function name.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts: Sure, but that's jQuery, not a pojo like `Shoes` :-)

Comment: @Bergi I added an example for the use of more varied signatures to my answer using `Shoes` as the base.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you are aware, the issue is `this` is not set on `getter` and `setter`, so why don't you set it?

```js
function createGetterSetter(getter, setter) {
  return function(arg) {
    if (arguments.length === 0) {
      return getter.call(this); // pass this to getter
    } else {
      setter.call(this, arg); // pass this to setter
      return this;
    };
  };
};

function Shoes() { this._color = null; this._style = null; }
Shoes.prototype.constructor = Shoes;

Shoes.prototype.color = createGetterSetter(
    function() { return this._color; },
    function(arg) { this._color = arg; });

Shoes.prototype.style = createGetterSetter(
    function() { return this._style; },
    function(arg) { this._style = arg; });

var cool_shoes = new Shoes().color('glitter').style('platform')
document.write(cool_shoes.color())
```

Comment: Clean and simple -- thank you for a great general-purpose method (and the glittery shoes).

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is already great but I'm going to try and go a step further. Sometimes getters and setters require more than just 0 and 1 arguments respectively, so I put together something a little more comprehensive:

```js
function Chain() {
  this._methods = {};
}

Chain.prototype.overload = function(key, method) {
  if (typeof key !== 'string') {
    throw new TypeError('key must be a string.');
  }
  if (typeof method !== 'function') {
    throw new TypeError('method must be a function.');
  }

  let attr, len = method.length;

  if ((attr = (
          this._methods.hasOwnProperty(key) && this._methods[key]
        ) || {}
      ) && attr[len]) {
    throw new RangeError(`method ${key} of length ${len} already exists.`);
  }
  
  attr[len] = method;
  
  if (!this._methods.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    this._methods[key] = attr;
    
    this[key] = function (...args) {
      let method = this._methods[key][args.length];
      
      if (typeof method !== 'function') {
        throw new ReferenceError(`method ${key} of length ${args.length} does not exist.`);
      }

      let value = method.apply(this, args);
      
      return (typeof value === 'undefined' ? this : value);
    }
  }
};

function Shoes() { this._color = null; this._style = null;}
Shoes.prototype = new Chain();

Shoes.prototype.overload('color', function() { return this._color; });
Shoes.prototype.overload('color', function(arg) { this._color = arg; });

Shoes.prototype.overload('style', function() { return this._style; });
Shoes.prototype.overload('style', function(arg) { this._style = arg; });

Shoes.prototype.overload('value', function() {
  return { color: this._color, style: this._style };
});
Shoes.prototype.overload('value', function(attr) { return this[attr](); });
Shoes.prototype.overload('value', function(attr, arg) { this[attr](arg); });

var cool_shoes = new Shoes().color('glitter').style('platform');
document.write(JSON.stringify(cool_shoes.value()));
```

Basically we construct a `Chain()` as the `Shoes.prototype` so we can overload the member methods for instances of `Shoes()`.

The `overload()` function takes a `key` and a `method`, determines the amount of arguments in the method's signature, and adds it to the available signatures for the method name given by `key`. If there is already a signature with the amount of arguments in the specified function, `overload()` will throw an error. If a function with an undeclared signature is invoked, it will throw an error as well.

Otherwise, setters chain properly (assuming they don't return anything) and getters return their values correctly.

### Update

As requested, here is a version of `Chain()` offered as a mixin instead of a super class:

```
function chain() {
  let _methods = {};

  return function overload(key, method) {
    if (typeof key !== 'string') {
      throw new TypeError('key must be a string.');
    }
    if (typeof method !== 'function') {
      throw new TypeError('method must be a function.');
    }

    let attr, len = method.length;

    if ((attr = (
            _methods.hasOwnProperty(key) && _methods[key]
          ) || {}
        ) && attr[len]) {
      throw new RangeError(`method ${key} of length ${len} already exists.`);
    }

    attr[len] = method;

    if (!_methods.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      _methods[key] = attr;

      this[key] = function (...args) {
        let method = _methods[key][args.length];

        if (typeof method !== 'function') {
          throw new ReferenceError(`method ${key} of length ${args.length} does not exist.`);
        }

        let value = method.apply(this, args);

        return (typeof value === 'undefined' ? this : value);
      }
    }
  };
}
```

#### Usage:

```
Shoes.prototype.overload = chain();
```

Comment: Lovely stuff!  To fit into my application, I think Chain() would have to be a mixin rather than a super class since I already have class hierarchy in my models.

Comment: @fearless_fool as requested, I updated my answer with a mixin version.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
function ToyClass() { this._c = 0; }

ToyClass.prototype.constructor = ToyClass;

function addFn( CLASS, ident, uncurriedMutation ) {
    CLASS.prototype[ident] = function( ...args ) {
      uncurriedMutation( this ).apply(this, args )
      return this
    }
}

addFn(ToyClass, 'increase', function( instance ){
    return function(){
        (instance._c)++
    }
})

const testCase = new ToyClass().increase()

console.log(testCase._c) // will be '1'
```

[Link to repl](https://repl.it/CRzg)

edit: [Simplified version.](https://repl.it/CRzg/1) Thanks @Patrick Roberts

Comment: The currying seems a little redundant... why do you need to pass an `instance` to an outer scope when you're already passing `this` to the actual mutator? e.g. the body of the mutator could just as easily be `this._c++`

Comment: Thanks. I suspected there to be a special name in the setting of OOP.

Comment: So the redundance can be avoided by using `addFn = (C, id, m) => { C.prototpye[id] = (...args) => m.apply(this, args) }` ? Nice! I was thinking of a solution that is not JS specific, though :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm late to the party as well, but I thought this was an interesting question.  Here's a solution that dynamically creates chainable getters and setters for all properties found in an object.  You could easily limit it to only make them for properties starting with `_`, but for simplicity, this does all of them.

All you need is:

```
Object.keys(new Shoes()).forEach(field => {
    let name = field.slice(1); // Remove underscore

    Shoes.prototype[name] = function(val) {
        if (val) {
            this[field] = val;
            return this;
        }

        return this[field];
    };
});
```

[Full example.](https://jsfiddle.net/Kredit/tgq3fck2/)

It creates a new function in the `Shoes` prototype that serves as a getter and setter.  Using `cool_shoes.color("red")` will set the `_color` property to `red`, and can be retrieved by just calling the function with no arguments (`cool_shoes.color() === "red"`).

I was looking into creating this functionality without explicitly creating all the getters and setters using the new [`Proxy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) object, but couldn't figure it out.  Maybe you'll have more luck with it!

Comment: I was originally going to use `Proxy` as well, but I figured that'd be a bit overkill, especially considering that it has no polyfills available for backwards compatibility. I took a more OOP approach myself, whereas your approach seems more functional.